# What are the jobs where a technical background can be a leverage but you do not do the actual nitty-gritty technical work?

Tags: career-development, careers, career-switch

I have a degree in electrical and electronics engineering. I have 3 years of working experience in total. My previous job of 2 years had 50/50 programming and engineering work. However, I'm currently working as a software dev where it is 100% programming.

I realized I do not enjoy the nitty-gritty technical work and would like to change to a career that requires less technical skills but focuses more on other aspects like design/human interaction/business etc. If I can find a job where my previous experience wouldn't go to waste and instead can act as a leverage, that would be perfect.

I tried searching for such jobs on Linkedin but no luck so far.

Are there any job titles that fit?

Comment: Solutions design, Solutions engineer, and sales are positions that you can often move into

Comment: Product Management can be a promising career path building on technical experience. Check this out. http://productleaders.org/posts/what-is-the-pragmatic-marketing-framework/

Comment: Industrial Design

Answer (score 4):

Engineering and management do not have much in common. Although you can learn about management as an engineer, by interacting with the managers, it will not be enough, usually.

You can try my approach: move from pure engineer / developer to team lead / (software) project manager. Once you have good experience with that (it can be as little as one year, usually two are required in job offers), you can move forward to hunt a more attractive job.

---

In the meanwhile, you can read the countless books written on the subject of management. Please be aware that management itself has a lot of fields and branches, so get an overview first, and then decide what you want to pursue.

---

Bottom line: do not be afraid to switch activities. I did it several times, and it always worked. Just be careful to prepare at least partially, to make the transition smooth, not sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Management? If you lead a team of engineers/developers/... you might be focusing mainly on design and the other points you gave, and they take care of the ground work. Of course your experience is important so that you know how to guide them and also are able to check and, if needed, correct their work, but you will do less "nitty-gritty work".

If you can get a position as technical manager or what to look for exactly (team lead, scrum master,...) is another question of course, but management as a general direction sounds like what you describe.
It might be easier to work your way up inside a company, but there are also sometimes companies hiring for a leading role; e.g. start-ups that notice that they might need someone with experience to organize everything.

As a fair warning, you will also get other aspects then, e.g. (company) politics. Be sure that you are ok with that before looking for such a position.